# What is an easy way to trigger a page fault?

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm looking for an easy way to trigger a real page fault (and not a segfault resulting from accessing an already mapped address or a protected address).

What could be one?

I thought of simply run

```
int main(void) {
    int *x = 1000;
    *x = 2000;
}
```

But it does not seem to result in a page fault but rather a memory violation.

Comment: [Page fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) is usually handled by operating system.

Comment: Yes but I have a way to handle it myself. I just don't know how to trigger one.

Comment: @anotherCode245 How do you handle it ?

Comment: On what OS/Architecture/CPU are you, and how are you handling it?

Comment: @anotherCode245 In this case, I believe `mmap()` a file, and read from it should be enough.

Comment: I can handle page faults with [this library](http://dune.scs.stanford.edu/). Want to do it on a x86_64 linux system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [`mmap()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) a disk file, and read from or write to it should be enough. At least it is enough on Linux.

Comment: @anotherCode245 Please follow the link in my answer, there is an example in that page.

Comment: the idea is good, but to cause a page fault, you need to access outside of mmap()-ed region

Comment: Well, isn't a pagefault triggered if the mapping is not yet in the TLB? So as a first access to this mmap-region I should have a page fault and the pagefault handler put this mapping in the TLB ?

Comment: @BЈовић Why 'outside of mmap()-ed region'? After `mmap()` return, if the file is not actually mapped, trying to access the region will cause some page faults, then OS will map that file; if the file is already mapped, then some page faults already triggered.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Linux, you can also exploit [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)'s copy-on-write behaviour:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int pid = 0, retcode = 0, poof = 0;
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        poof = 1; /* Page fault */
    } else {
        waitpid(pid, &retcode, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another way to do it is:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    long pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    unsigned char *p = malloc(pagesize + 1); /* Cross page boundaries. Page fault may occur depending on your allocator / libc implementation. */
    p[0] = 0;        /* Page fault. */
    p[pagesize] = 1; /* Page fault. */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux, you can emulate segmentation fault and bus error by sending signals to the process. See [man signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

To emulate segmentation fault of a process with pid=1234, type in terminal :

```
kill -s 11 1234
```

To emulate bus error of a process with pid=1234, type in terminal :

```
kill -s 10 1234
```

In c, you can use [raise()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/raise.3.html) or [kill()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) function

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main() {
    raise(SIGBUS);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The asker needs a "page fault", not a "segmentation fault".

Comment: @leeduhem [Page fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) - segmentation fault and bus error are types of page faults.